# In the next page $_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"] = NULL

Tags: php, html

I had upload file with POST and it seems to works fine, but after I go to the next page I can't use the file with the location in the global varible: $_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"]
because it's null. I don't know why, I used this code before and it worked fine...

Here is the code:

**www/step1.php**

```
if (isset($_POST["check_if_press"]) && $_POST["check_if_press"] == "Upload") 

{

if (!empty($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"])) 

{

  header("Location: ./step2_1.php");

  }else     echo "Please select a file";

}

<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 Upload file: <input type='file' name='myfile' /><br />

 <input type='Submit' name='check_if_press' value='Upload'  />

</form>
```

**www/step2_1.php**

```
echo  $_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"];
```

Now I get NULL printed on the screen.

When I used POST without the arguments :

```
action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF
```

But with:

```
action="./step2.php"
```

Instead, It work, but than I cant use the upload check .

Thanks,

Yonatan.

Answer (score 3):

The file is only present in `$_FILES` within the scope of the post.  What's happening here is:

1. User is posting a file to `step1`
2. `step1` is doing something with the file, then telling the user to go to `step2` (by means of the location header)
3. In response to the location header, user is making a GET request to `step2`, no posted file is associated

You're going to need to either post the file directly to `step2` (which you said worked, just didn't have the logic of `step1`) and put your server-side file checking logic there, or in `step1` store the file somewhere on the server (either save it to the file system, store it in a database, maybe store it in session which I don't recommend, etc.) where it can be accessed by `step2`.

`step2` is a completely separate request from `step1` and doesn't have access to anything within the scope of `step1`.

Comment: or where the location header is, do: `include(step2.php);` that could also work

Comment: @Neal: Good point.  These scripts may be able to be combined for functionality depending on how they're designed and what they do.  Might need to change some code to avoid side-effects, but it's certainly doable.

Answer (score 0):

The temporary file is deleted at the end of your post script, so you'll need to copy it to another location before you redirect:

```
if (!empty($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"])) 

{
  //COPY THE FILE TO ANOTHER LOCATION HERE...

  header("Location: ./step2_1.php");

  }else     echo "Please select a file";

}
```